Email Editor: show other field instead of Full name on selecting contact or user from suggestions
I'm seeking a solution wherein, upon typing "contact/users" in the email editor, upon selecting a contact from suggestions, it displays only the full name of that contact or user unless the email is manually typed, in which case it shows the email address. We're encountering an issue where users sometimes select contacts with the same name but different business units, resulting in emails being sent to the wrong recipient. This problem arises not only in case feeds but also in global email actions within Salesforce. Is there a way to either display a combination of Fullname + another field (e.g., Business Unit) as shown in my screenshot, or show a different field instead of the full name? Can we configure mouse hover behavior for this? Please refrain from suggesting appending the last name of a contact, as that is not a route we wish to pursue. Thank you.
I have appended a last name but this is not a solution we can accept, and also tried to search setting in email global action.
